# var_dump (PHP) equivalent for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for an equivalent of `var_dump` in **node.js**.

I'd like to send the content of the **request** / **response** circular structure as a part of the response.

I know I can see it in the console, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To get what you’d get in the console by using `console.log` as a string for sending to the client as part of your response, you can use [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options).

```
"use strict";

const http = require("http");
const util = require("util");

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=utf-8");
    response.end(util.inspect(request));
}).listen(8000, "::1");
```

Answer (score 6):

**You can simply use the NPM package var_dump**

```
npm install var_dump --save-dev
```

Usage:

```
const var_dump = require('var_dump')
    
var variable = {
  'data': {
    'users': {
      'id': 12,
      'friends': [{
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'John Doe'
      }]
    }
  }
}
 
// print the variable using var_dump
var_dump(variable)
```

This will print:

```
object(1) {
    ["data"] => object(1) {
        ["users"] => object(2) {
            ["id"] => number(12)
            ["friends"] => array(1) {
                [0] => object(2) {
                    ["id"] => number(1)
                    ["name"] => string(8) "John Doe"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/var_dump

Thank me later!

Answer (score 1):

There is a npm package called [`circular-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-json), it's very good to use. I wonder why it is not built-in...

Comment: `circular-json` package has been deprecated. This package's author recommends to use `flatted` package: https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted